# Analysis Ideas for Unusual Observational Time Series w/Treatment

Tags: time-series, anova, panel-data, treatment-effect, intervention-analysis

I am studying some retrospective time series survey (panel) data, sometimes with an intervening treatment, and would like feedback on an analysis concept to test for a treatment effect.

Each observation is a small set of ordinal-scaled surveys, and could be obtained either in the broken out form, as 9 questions with response scale 0-3, or as the sum (0-27). Each participant filled out a number of these surveys over a period of nearly a year, although the specific number of surveys, and the specific days on which they were completed by a given individual varies widely. In addition, a subset of the participants were subjected to a treatment someplace during that year. The time point at which these treatments were done is quite variable, but the duration of treatment is close to fixed, at around a month.

I am interested in whether the treatment is correlated with a significant change in the survey responses. (For the moment I'll speak as though we are only looking at the 0-27 summary score, although I'm happy to be told that I need to analyze the broken out score instead.)

Assume that I can approximately match subjects who were treated with those who were not. That is, for example, suppose that the last survey taken by subject 1 (S1) took place on day 30 (D30), and that S1 the underwent treatment, and did another survey on D60 (recall that the treatment takes about a month). In this case I'll just use that one before, and one after survey as the data for S1. I can almost certainly find a subject, S2, who has surveys 30 days apart, so S1 and S2 are matched. In fact, since the treatments are almost all ~30days, if I were only to consider two surveys: one pre- and one post-treatment, I can almost certainly find dozens -- perhaps hundreds of subjects matched in this way, and probably a simple ANOVA will serve for testing the hypothesis of the treatment effect.

However, what I really have is several surveys before and after treatment, and I can probably match up some such subjects, analogous to the above, but many fewer would have surveys on all the same days. I'd like to take advantage of all that data, and I'm imagining something like a linear fit to each set (pre- and post-) for each subject and their match, and then comparing the slopes and intercepts of those linear fits in an ANOVA, as above.

But this raises all sorts of issues, like what do I do with the MSE of those fits, and so forth. Also, the matching procedure seems less reasonable in this case, as (as above) I can't really match multiple survey dates too often, so will have few matched controls.

I'm hoping that someone can suggest an approach to this data.

Comment: This is repeated measurements data, so look into models for that!

Comment: Yes, the ANOVA is a repeated measures ANOVA. Do you have a more specific guidance?